# Reuse Ubuntu Partition from internal HDD, which is connected to another PC as external HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I had internal HDD connected to my pc with dual boot on it (Windows 7 + Ubuntu).

Then, I bough new SDD, installed Windows 10.

Now, I have connected HDD with SATA to USB enclosure (Transcend StoreJet 2.5) ) to use it as External HDD.

How to reuse the Ubuntu installed in my previous (External) HDD?

I would like boot the Ubuntu from external HDD without moving it to SDD.

Comment: Can't give detailed help, but you will need to reinstall grub so it is loaded upon boot and is informed about the current state of operating systems on your computer.